# How is circular motion possible on a banked road when there is no Friction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force, free-body-diagram

It is given here that the maximum safe speed of a vehicle on a banked road having coefficient of friction $0$, is $V =\sqrt{R g \tan \theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle of banking. I can't understand how circular motion is possible without friction.

Comment: A banked road without friction has a component of gravity towards the center of the circle. Do a free body diagram and it will become obvious.

Comment: Gravity has a ***horizontal*** component?

Comment: No, the normal force exerted by the road has a horizontal component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need for circular motion is **Centripetal Force**. Definition:

*Centripetal force is a force that makes a body follow a curved path: its direction is always orthogonal to the velocity of the body, toward the fixed point of the instantaneous center of curvature of the path. Centripetal force is generally the cause of circular motion.*

If the road is **flat**, the centripetal force is provided by **Friction** between the tyres of the car and the road. This image show how:
[image]

If the there is no friction and the road is flat, the car would not be able to turn, it would keep sliding in the same direction.

So, if there is no friction, there has to be some force that can provide that necessary centripetal force. If the road is **banked**, the **horizontal component of the Normal vector** of the car that is going towards the centre of turn can act as the centripetal force. Hence, the car can turn on a banked road even without friction. Here is how:
[image]

Comment: Are you IIT ian?

Comment: Haha no. All Indians who know a bit of Physics are not in the IITs. I am doing a Bachelors in Science, not Engineering.

Comment: Good night parth

Comment: I have still doubt about, why there is not gravitational acceleration component along surface of road ?

Comment: You mean down the slope? $mgSin\theta$ is there of course. Normal force exists because of gravity only, it's a reaction to gravity (Newton's Third Law).

Comment: So the component of mgsin{theta} along horizontal direction will be mgsin{theta}cos{theta} .so why it is not taken in consideration

Comment: Can't they add up

Comment: See, they are the same forces, Normal and $mg$. So no, you can't add them up.