# What's the direction of the friction the wall offers when the performers cycle on the vertical wall?

Tags: friction

In the acrobatic below,the performers move horizontally so the friction should be horizontal(The kinetic frictional force is always
in the direction opposite to the
velocity of the object.).Since all the force are horizontal what force is against the gravity?[image]

Comment: They move, but horizontally. What prevents them from falling down is static friction in the vertical,  I think. They increase the force pressing them to the wall by centrifugal force, and thus the friction. Maybe this helps? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397316/how-do-we-explain-defying-gravity-by-objects-on-the-wall-of-a-rotating-drum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wall on the photo is not strictly vertical - it is cone-shaped.

Generally, if you move on a pad and this pad acts with a force on you, then *by definition* the projection of the force to the plane parallel to the pad is called *friction* while the the perpendicular component is the *reaction*. Reaction is the force that prevents you to fall through the floor when you just stand on it.

We might actually totally neglect friction and the trick on the would still work (once they are moving, they might be moving on and on if also the friction in the bicycle is negligible). The important force is the reaction. As one can easily imagine, the reaction - perpendicular to the wall, can be decomposed into the horizontal direction (centripetal force) and a vertical direction which aims upwards. This **vertical component of the reaction force acts against gravity**.

(The faster they go, the larger the centripetal force $F_c=v^2/R$ and, since the slope of the wall is fixed, the larger is also the vertical component of the reaction force $F_v$. Hence of they cycled slowly, they would go down. If they cycled too fast, then the gravity would be smaller than $F_v$ and they'd get to cycle on a higher position where the radius is larger.)

If the wall was exactly vertical, this trick could not work.

Comment: Thanks.So if the wall is strictly vertical,the performer will fall off,right?

Comment: I believe so... I'm adding this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Friction always exist in direction opposite of motion i.e. friction opposes relative motion. so, here in case of cyclist it will act in horizontal direction opposite to their motion and in vertical direction as they have tendency to move down so it will act in upwards direction.

Comment: Stated like this, it's incorrect. The "direction of motion" is undefined if the system isn't point-like, as each point of the system can have a different velocity (think of a wheel). You must specifically refer to the point of contact and, if this point has the same velocity as the wall, then the orientation of the friction force might be tricky to prove. In any case, *never* use the motion of the center of mass, since the friction force doesn't apply at this point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks.But I cant understand that why kinetic friction can coexist with static friction.How to define "the tendency to move" when it has already moved?